# Error when running Powershell, tabcmd needs to be initialised

Tags: powershell

I am trying to login to Tableau server using Powershell. I am using this code and getting this error. all the paths will come from Excel input. Code snippet:
I need to initialise the tabcmd somehow. can someone please help?

```
$C = Get-Credential

./tabcmd login -s https://analytics4tst.jll.com -t gfm -u $C.UserName -p $C.GetNetworkCredential().Password



#cd $path

#Connect to Excel
$excel=new-object -com excel.application

#link to the Excel workbook
$wb=$excel.workbooks.open("C:\List.xlsx")

#Tell it which sheet to look at
$sh=$wb.Sheets.Item("Pics")
$path = $sh.Cells.Item(4, 2).Text

$path

#indicate the last cell in the used range
$endRow=$sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(11).row
```

The term './tabcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
 file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was in
cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that Powershell doesn't know what `tabcmd` is about. This either means that the command is not in path or it is not installed at all. The first case, in plain English, means that `tabcmd` is installed, but Powershell doesn't know where to look for it. To work-around, use explicit path like `C:\Program Files\Tableau\<some version>\bin\tabcmd`. The actual path depends on where Tableau was installed, so you need to find out the right path.

The second case is related to the software installation. Make sure you have installed `tabcmd` to your local computer. As per the [documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm) (my emphasis) it is only installed on server per default:

> Note: When you install Tableau Server, the tabcmd utility is installed
>   automatically on the primary server node. *If you want to install it on
>   other computers, you need to download the installer* from the Tableau
>   website.

Comment: When I explicitly add the path it works, but I need the path to come from from user input which will be in Excel.

Comment: I need something like this..

./tabcmd = $path = $sh.Cells.Item(4, 2).Text

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to store application path in Excel workbook. Why not install the tool on a standardized path?